# Reload a layer with new JSON data in gvNIX

Tags: json, layer, gvnix

I´m surfing inside this tool but I have problems to reload a existing layer with new data.

I have the layer Owner and I have added filters just in the bottom of the layers selector. This filter send an ajax request that returns a JSON and I need to put this data inside this existing layer.

Is it possible to do that only with Leaflet library or I have to use customs gvNIX javascript functions declared in leaflet.ext.gvnix.map.js?

I can't find how to do that with js

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The classes declared on `leaflet.ext.gvnix.map.js` are defined to integrate gvNIX generated `.tagx`  on `.jspx` pages with *leaflet* component.

Of course, you can modify `.jspx` to include whatever you need on page or customize any gvNIX component (or duplicate it to extend its functionalities) to fit your requirements.

By example, you can create your own `field.tagx` to adjust its legend representation.

A good practice to archive it is create a new directory on `WEB-INF/tags` folder where create your custom tags. Then, in the `.jspx`, include a new *xmlns* prefix pointing to your tag folder. This way, you can update gvNIX tags library (from new gvNIX versions) without lose yours customizations.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, I´ve seen that and I´m trying to edit toc.tagx to add my own code. The problem it´s understand all JS logic under this tags. How can I get the data represented inside of a layer? Is there any function to do that ?. Thanks @jmvivo

Comment: Well, I know current `leaflet.ext.gvnix.map.js`  is a little bit cryptic. Future versions will be clearer. We are planing to make easy extend and create new layer types (including groups, wms-t, one-geometry layer, etc...), but I can't tell you when it will be. Sorry.

Comment: I agree, it´s not clear trace this JS. Anyway, it´s a great job all new tags that used in jspx files. Maybe in the next versions could it be a good functionality create generic functions like put data in an existing layer or add new layer. Thanks !